# Retrieving text from a combobox that has been bound to a database table

Tags: java, jcombobox, data-retrieval

I have created a jCombobox that is bound to a database table. I have modified the renderer code to display the field properly, in this case a persons surname. However when I try and retrieve the selected text from the combobox using jComboBox1.getSelectedValue().asString, I get the sort of text that would have been displayed if I had not modified the renderer code.
e.g. "combotest.Staff[ staffId=M2653101 ]" 
How do I retrieve the text as it is displayed?

Comment: How does your JComboBox get a getSelectedValue()? [The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) does not show it has this method.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `getRenderer()` method in `JComboBox`, but the cleanest solution would be to move the transformation from the renderer code to a static method somewhere (or even better to the `toString()` of your object), and then call this method from the renderer, and also from the other place.

Comment: Sorry but I'm pretty new to Java, how do I get from getRenderer to the text. When I retrieve using getRenderer I get a pretty long string which includes ",Text = Smith," Smith being the value I want to retrieve presumably there is a neat way of accessing that.

Comment: I depends on how you implemented the renderer code to display the surname. But I doubt that there is a neat way to retrieve what you want.